# Problems with resizing divs with jquery on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, addeventlistener

I have done resizing two divs on my page. The function that is written in jquery, does it properly. Problem is on Chrome/Firefox, in some occasions(rarely) when function is executed, the divs are returned to the original size. Refreshing the page, the divs are resized correctly.
On debug function resizes the divs correctly, but when exiting the jquery function the divs are returned to original sizes. Jquery function where the problem appears:

```
// Cleanup functions for the document ready method
if (document.addEventListener) {
    DOMContentLoaded = function() {
       document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false);
       jQuery.ready();
};
```

While passing the last line( }; ) div are returned to original size, before that everything worked correctly. Using jquery-1.7.2.js.
Has anybody had similar problem? On IE11 everything works fine.

Comment: can you post the page and the code where this problem is happening? it's very hard to understand what the issue is from your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that divs resized before document finished loading, when document ready, browser renders the page for resizing if needed, and caused the divs to resize to its original size. maybe put the resize div function after document.ready instead.